# trying to implement a side navigation with a toggle button in <mat-toolbar>?

Tags: angular

I am having a side navigation panel with some details.
In the header component I am having a button which should toggle the side navigation.
I have implemented a toolbar using .My requirement is that when i click on  that button, the side navigation should toggle in and out.
How to implement it ?

My navigation.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar>
      </mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item>Accounts</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>UserProfile</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>Contact me</mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>Gspeed</mat-list-item>


  </mat-list>

 </mat-sidenav-container>
```

header.component.html

```
<body [ngClass]="selectedStyle" ><div >

    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedStyle" >
       <option *ngFor="let s of styles" [ngValue]="s">{{s}}</option>
    </select>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSidenav()">
      <mat-icon >Details</mat-icon></button>

    </div>
   </body>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  styles: string[] = [];
  selectedStyle: string;
  open: false;
   toggleSidenav(){
     open: !this.open;
   }


  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.styles = ['red','green','blue','none'];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your togglelSSideNav() function
and use ngIf to check open status

```
     toggleSidenav(){
     this.open=!this.open;
   }
```

Comment: I changed  open: boolean;
  toggleSidenav(){
    this.open= !this.open;
  }   and also used  <div>
    <app-navigation *ngIf="open"></app-navigation>
  </div> in app.component.html but getting error: rc/app/app.component.html:8:28 - error TS2339: Property 'open' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

8     <app-navigation *ngIf="open"></app-navigation>
                             ~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is answering the question based on a complex component hierarchy. I didn't realise your header and sidebar components were both in app component. In which case it's a trivial solution.

The two common ways of doing this are

1. bubble events from event source to interested components. In your case this would mean bubbling through the common path between header component and sidebar component.

By this, I mean you have a series of child -> parent event handling relationships like this:

```
<child (event)="handleEvent($event)">
</child>
```

Where event is some event emitter emitting events of `T`: `@Output() event: EventEmitter<T> = new EventEmitter<T>();`

And then when you have bubbled up to the common ancestor, you have a series of parent -> child relationships like this:

```
<child [childEventResult]="eventResult">
</child>
```

Where `eventResult` is some property of type `T` and `childEventResult` is some input property of type `T`: `@Input() eventResult: T;`.

This is a tedious approach if you have a complex component hierarchy, or want to change the hierarchy.

2. Pass the data between a common service.

Inject the common service into both components. Set up a subject on the service. The interested component (sidebar) would subscribe to the subject, and the event source component (header) would send new values to the subject when an event happens.

```
export class MyService {
  private sidebarChange$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  // header updates the subject via this method
  updateSidebar(visible: boolean): void {
    this.sidebarChange$.next(visible);
  }

  // Sidebar subscribes to this. Needs a more suitable name
  sidebarChange(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.sidebarChange$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

This approach is better if you have a complex component structure, but I feel a bit unsure about leaking pure UI concerns into my services.

Comment: I am trying to implement  basic idea.In my header component the button on click is  calling the toggleSidenav() which is changing values of the variable open.Now how can I pass the value of this into my app.component.html  <app-navigation *ngIf="toggleSidenav()"></app-navigation>.My requirement is that the toggle should open only on that button click.Button click is happening but the value is not being passed to the <app-navigation *ngIf="toggleSidenav()">.How can i do that?Can you tell me please